# Best way to handle a function that takes no arguments but sometimes is called with events from bind?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, arguments

I know that I can use `event=None` and this works fine however PyCharm likes to complain about this as the event is never used in the function. What is the best way to satisfy PyCharm's inspector. For this notice:

[image]

Take this function:

```
def funct(event=None):
   #  do stuff
```

Where I have a button command that calls it:

```
tk.Button(root, text='Ok', command=funct)
```

Or a bind that can call it:

```
root.bind(<Return>, funct)
```

Now because binds always sent an event what is the best way to tell the function to accept calls to it with or without an argument and wont trip PyCharm's inspector.

Am I missing something or is this inspector just overly cautious?

I could change the bind to use a lambda and then I can remove `event=None` from the function:

```
root.bind(<Return>, lambda e: funct)
```

That seams like over kill for this.

I don't think I should just throw `event` in the function so PyCharm stops complaining that `event` is not used.

I have tried also to use `_` in the argument place however doing so requires some argument to be sent so I would have to perform a lambda in the button command for this to work and again feels like overkill.

So that leads me to my question.

Is there a know method of handling this that I am not aware of or do I have to just deal with the inspectors message always on my screen?

Note: I did try to remove this notice from the settings but I could not find the notice for this particular notification to remove...

Comment: Try this `_=None`

Comment: @IainShelvington would you look at that. That did exactly what I needed.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31286

Comment: @IainShelvington That will only work for positional parameters, not parameters passed by name.

Comment: Maybe: `**_` would work?

Comment: I would say not to worry about pycharm. Using `event=None` is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley I would ignore it if I could disable that notification. Its just really bugs me to see those squiggly lines when scrolling through my code. However the use if `_=None` has appeared to get rid of the notification so I will use that for now until I can find the correct notification to disable.

Comment: Hmmm, on my pycharm this only shows as greyed out instead of squiggly lines so it didn't bother me that much.

Comment: @HenryYik as you can see in the image those lines exist for me. It bugs my OCD and on top of that I have those inspection lines on the scroll bar to the right. I know its not hurting the code its just visually annoying.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I can feel it - it would drive me crazy. But just to be clear, what if you use `*args, **kwargs`? Do they also have the lines if unused?

Comment: @HenryYik yep I tested those options as well. Same line issue.

Comment: Unused parameters started with `_` are ignored, so `def funct(_event=None):` should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my needs the simple solution was to use `_=None` as mentioned by [Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington).

However for completeness sake I combined the use of `*args, **kwargs` with `_` to have a catch all that PyCharm does not complain about and will catch anything that is passed to the function be it positional or named.

Example:

```
def test(*_args, **_kwargs):
    print('test')


test()
test('1')
test(x='1')
```